# Chain Rule for multivariable functions to one variable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm trying to understand some questions about the chain rule of multivariable and how it relates with one variable functions.

Ok, so, imagine that I have two functions $f: U \subset E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow E$, where $E$ is a normed vector space.

Then, by the chain rule, the derivative of $f \circ \alpha$ in some point $a \in U$ is:

$(f \circ \alpha)'(a) = Df_{\alpha(a)} \cdot D\alpha_a$.

The point that I don't get is that $(f \circ \alpha)'(a)$ is a number, but $Df_{\alpha(a)} \cdot D\alpha_a$. is a linear application. So, I'm a little bit confused, can the number $(f \circ \alpha)'(a)$ be interpreted in some way by a linear application?

Thanks!

Comment: The composition of the linear transformation will simply give you a linear functional $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, and there is a natural isomorphism between these functionals and real numbers. (because they all have the form $T(x)=cx$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: The derivative of a single variable function *is* actually a linear map: what is usually called the derivative is but the coefficient of this linear map from $\bf R$ to $\bf R$.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ at $x\in\mathbb R$ is a number $c\in\mathbb R$ characterized by the fact that
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+ch+o(h^2).$$
The term $ch$ is essentially a linear map $h\mapsto ch$, which is entirely characterized by the number $c$, which is the derivative of $f$. That's how the derivative of a 1d function should be interpreted as a linear map. More conceptually, the tangent function $t(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h$ is a linear map (affine linear, to be exact) as a function of $h$, determined by the derivative. The actually linear part $f'(x)h$ is the linear map we're talking about.

For higher dimensions, this works exactly the same: If $\mathrm Df_x$ is the derivative of $f$ in $x$, then
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+\mathrm Df_x(h)+o(\vert h\vert^2).$$
Just like in the 1d case.